# C++: Array to pointer decay questions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to figure out exactly how the relationship works between arrays and pointers in C++.  I have read a number of threads and I feel as if it's just not sticking.  Looking at this short bit of code here:

```
int studentAge[5];
int *p = &studentAge[0];
```

I've read that the reference operator(&) creates an exception to the array->pointer decay rule.  So, from what I've read I believe they're saying that `&studentAge` is technically a pointer to 5 integer values, not a pointer to a single integer.  To elaborate more, is it right to say that its type will be `int(*)[5]`, which cannot convert to `int*`?

If it's a pointer to 5 integer values, then wouldn't that mean that it did, in fact, decay to a pointer? Or am I completely wrong in thinking this?

Furthermore, with this line of code:

```
p = studentAge;
```

Without the reference operator does the studentAge array now decay to a pointer?  I apologize if I'm all over the place with this, but as I stated before, I'm having a difficult time getting 100% clear on this.

Comment: That's not a reference, that's the "address-of" operator.

Comment: Also, `&studentAge` is a pointer to an *array* of 5 integers. `studentAge` is an array so this makes sense.

Comment: Also, `&x[i]` is equivalent to `&(x[i])`, not `(&x)[i]`.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c).

Comment: Oli, aren't the terms reference operator and address-of operator interchangeable?

Comment: No, there is no such thing as the "reference operator".  (Although the `&` operator technically doesn't have a name in the C++ standard, *references* are fundamentally different to addresses/pointers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take an array argument to a function, it will indeed decay to a pointer.  If you take a reference to an array, it will not.

```
#include <iostream>

void take_array(int arr[]) { // same as (int *arr)
    // prints sizeof int*
    std::cout << "take_array: " << sizeof arr << '\n';
    ++arr; // this works, you can increment a pointer
}


void take_array_ref(int (&arr)[10]) { // a reference to an array of int[10]
    // prints (sizeof int) * 10
    std::cout << "take_array_ref: " << sizeof arr << '\n';
    //++arr; // this fails to compile. you can't increment an array
}

int main() {
    int arr[10]; // sizeof arr == (sizeof int) * 10
    take_array(arr); // decays
    take_array_ref(arr); // doesn't decay

    int arr2[2];
    take_array(arr2);  // compiles because it decays
    //take_array_ref(arr2); // doesn't compile, type mismatch 
}
```

note that the first signature could also be `void take_array(int arr[1000]);` or any other value, it would still be the same as having a pointer; the output would still be the same, the `arr` parameter would still effectively be `int *`

Comment: Thank you!  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `&studentAge[0]` means `&(studentAge[0])`.

In the context of `studentAge[0]`, the array indeed decays to a pointer to the first element, i.e. of type `int *`.  This is then immediately dereferenced by the `[0]`, leaving a type of `int`.  You then finally take the address of that (with the *address-of* operator `&`), getting you back to an `int *`.

In short, `p = &studentAge[0]` is identical to `p = studentAge`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  In that case, how is & an exception to array->pointer decay?

Comment: It *is* an exception, but only when applied to an array.  In this context, you're applying it to something that's not an array.

Answer (score -2):

One important thing to note is when we define an array, the compiler allocates a contiguous block of memory.
Another important thing to note, that arrays are treated as pointers (references) in C/C++
So when we create any array say:

```
int studentAge[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

It allocates this array as a continuous memory block.

"studentAge" is basically an (int *) pointing to the start of the array

Therefore, the below 2 statements are basically doing the same thing

```
int *p = & (studentAge[0]);
int *p = studentAge;
```

Now to check if they are contiguous we can do the following:

```
std::cout << *p << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << *(p+1) << std::endl; // prints 2
std::cout << *(p+2) << std::endl; // prints 3
std::cout << *(p+3) << std::endl; // prints 4
std::cout << *(p+4) << std::endl; // prints 5
```

Comment: `studentAge` isn't "basically an `(int*)`". It *decays* into an `int*` as necessary, but it's **not** an `int*`. If it were, `sizeof(studentAge)` would return `sizeof(int*)` and it doesn.t